# What can a Muslim say in genuflection and prostration of prayers (Roku' and Sajdah)?

Tags: salat, dua, sajda

There are very nice Ayahs and Du'a to glorify Allah, like:

> يُسَبِّحُ لِلَّهِ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الْأَرْضِ الْمَلِكِ
> الْقُدُّوسِ الْعَزِيزِ الْحَكِيمِ - الجمعة 1
>
> [Whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth is exalting Allah , the Sovereign, the Pure, the Exalted in Might, the Wise](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=%2862:1:1%29)
>
> لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ سُبْحَانَكَ إِنِّي كُنْتُ مِنَ الظَّالِمِينَ - الانبيا 19
>
> [There is no deity except You; exalted are You. Indeed, I have been of the wrongdoers](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=%2821:87:19%29)

I think the prayers would be so beautiful with these Ayahs.

Can Muslims use similar Ayah or Du'a to glorify Allah in genuflection and prostration? If yes are they enough, or the normal genuflection and prostration sentences also should be added? An answer containing ideas of different schools is more than welcome.

Comment: this question has no quality, someone can open any fiqh book and see the answer, or even search online.  Here we expect questions to be of high quality, questions people would normally not find easily, questions that are use to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In rukoo', you can say the following:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

[image]

Listen to the audio of the du'a [here](http://abdurrahman.org/zikr/Hisn_al_Muslim/sounds/Prayer_Bowing.mp3)

---

**In Sujood, you can say the following:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Listen to the audio of the du'a [here](http://abdurrahman.org/zikr/Hisn_al_Muslim/sounds/Prayer_Prostrating.mp3)

---

Regarding supplicating using verses from Qur'an, there is no objection for this provided one should not intend the recitation of the Quran, rather he should intend supplicating Allaah.

Rukoo' and sujud is for supplicating to Allaah and praising him.

All the Jurists (may Allaah have mercy upon them) have agreed that the recitation of the Quran whilst bowing or prostrating is dislikable.

This is because of the [narration of Ibn Abbass](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/236) (radiallahu anhu) from the Messenger (salallahu alayhi' wassalam).

> Ibn 'Abbas reported: The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him)
>   drew aside the curtain (of his apartment) and (he saw) people in rows
>   (saying prayer) behind Aba Bakr. And he said: Nothing remains of the
>   glad tidings of apostlehood, except good visions which a Muslim sees
>   or someone is made to see for him. And see that I have been forbidden
>   to recite the Qur'an in the state of bowing and prostration. So far as
>   Ruk'u is concerned, extol in it the Great and Glorious Lord, and while
>   prostrating yourselves be earnest in supplication, for it is fitting
>   that your supplications should be answered.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ مَنْصُورٍ، وَأَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ
>   وَزُهَيْرُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ قَالُوا حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ بْنُ عُيَيْنَةَ،
>   أَخْبَرَنِي سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ سُحَيْمٍ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ بْنِ عَبْدِ
>   اللَّهِ بْنِ مَعْبَدٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ كَشَفَ
>   رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم السِّتَارَةَ وَالنَّاسُ صُفُوفٌ
>   خَلْفَ أَبِي بَكْرٍ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّهُ لَمْ يَبْقَ
>   مِنْ مُبَشِّرَاتِ النُّبُوَّةِ إِلاَّ الرُّؤْيَا الصَّالِحَةُ يَرَاهَا
>   الْمُسْلِمُ أَوْ تُرَى لَهُ أَلاَ وَإِنِّي نُهِيتُ أَنْ أَقْرَأَ
>   الْقُرْآنَ رَاكِعًا أَوْ سَاجِدًا فَأَمَّا الرُّكُوعُ فَعَظِّمُوا
>   فِيهِ الرَّبَّ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ وَأَمَّا السُّجُودُ فَاجْتَهِدُوا فِي
>   الدُّعَاءِ فَقَمِنٌ أَنْ يُسْتَجَابَ لَكُمْ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

**Sources:**

- [Hisn Al Muslim Min Athkar Al Kitaab Was Sunnah](http://abdurrahman.org/zikr/Hisn_al_Muslim/frame.html) by Sa'eed Al
  Qahtani
- [Reciting Du'aa from the Quran in Rukoo' and Sujood](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90357)

Comment: +1, Shia believes similar to what you have stated: what is Wajib in genuflection and prostration is saying a Dhikr, but what to say is up to ourselves. However, some special Dhikr are introduced as Mustahab like reciting "سبحان الله" for  3 or 5 or 7 times or instead reciting "سبحان ربی العظیم و بحمده" in genuflection and "سبحان ربی الأعلی و بحمده" in prostration for 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 times. Note that reciting Quran is not Dhike unless your intention is not reciting Quran but reciting a Dhikr acquired from Quran!

Comment: Is there any reason the supplications are provided as images instead of text?

Comment: @goldPseudo No particular reason. The source I took it from was images. So, it was easier for me to put it that way and I feel it looks clearer than usual.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

In Ruku' you say:

> سُبْحَانَ رَبِّيَ الْعَظِيمِ سُبْحَانَ رَبِّيَ الْعَظِيمِ
>
> 'Subahana Rabbial-'azim, Subhana Rabbial-'azim (Glory be to my Lord
>   Almighty, Glory be to my Lord Almighty)

[Sunan Annasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/12/117)

This is how the Prophet (May Allah's blessings and peace be upon Him) did it, and so this is how we do it. [Backup](http://sunnah.com/adab/10/2)

Comment: So it means that we are not allowed to say anything else?